Long lived Cloud SQL Python Connector with IAM authentication gives intermittent "Broken pipe" and "Server disconnected" errors
I have a Flask server running in Google Cloud Run; to serve some requests, the server needs to query a Postgres DB that lives in Google Cloud SQL. I have setup the Flask server such that when the application starts, it creates an instance of sqlalchemy.Engine, following the Cloud SQL Python Connector Flask example:
from os import environ

import pg8000

from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector
from sqlalchemy import Engine

def _create_engine_for_cloud_sql_iam_user(*, instance_name: str, db_name: str) -> Engine:
    iam_user = environ["CLOUD_SQL_IAM_USER"]
    connector = Connector()

    def getconn():
        pg8000.dbapi.paramstyle = "pyformat"
        return connector.connect(
            f"my-project:us-central1:{instance_name}",
            "pg8000",
            user=iam_user,
            db=db_name,
            enable_iam_auth=True,
        )

    return create_engine(
        "postgresql+pg8000://",
        creator=getconn,
    )

# the Flask server app initialization
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    my_db = _create_engine_for_cloud_sql_iam_user(instance_name="my_srvr", db_name="my_db")

The CLOUD_SQL_IAM_USER has a service account email setup with the proper permissions to access the DB, etc.
When a request comes in, it uses the Engine with:
with my_db.connect() as conn:
    # do some query


All works fine, but in the app's open telemetry I see requests failing to these endpoints:

https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/instances/my-srvr:generateEphemeralCert
https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/instances/my-srvr/connectSettings

Those requests happen roughly every 26 minutes and fail intermittently with aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnected or aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
So, my question is twofold: is there a way that I can prevent those requests from happening?, and Can I just ignore the failing ones?

This is a symptom of how the Python Connector works with Cloud Run. The Python Connector runs a background task to refresh the ephemeral certificate for connecting to Cloud SQL. When Cloud Run throttles the CPU, the background refresh cannot run and results in these errors you're seeing.
We're going to be adding support for a lazy refresh specifically for Cloud Run. See the issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/805.
Meanwhile, you can either:

Enable always allocated CPU (which might be worth it if it's a high load service)
Connect without the Python Connector and still use IAM Authentication (see here)
Use the Cloud SQL Proxy with a multi-container setup (See here).

If it were me, I'd probably go for option 2.

Thank you for the reply and clear explanation @enocom. Option 2 seems ideal for my case indeed!

Happy to hear it! FWIW the Python Connector will get last refresh soon.

v1.10.0+ has this functionality
